# How to read & modify value of node in linked tree?

Tags: rust, tree, reference-counting, borrowing, interior-mutability

I'm struggling with the implementation of tree structure in Rust.
Particularly, getting and modifying the node's value. What is idiomatic way to work with the value?

Note: the implementation is given and cannot be changed.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

// Definition for a binary tree node.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
  pub val: i32,
  pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
  pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

impl TreeNode {
  #[inline]
  pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    TreeNode {
      val,
      left: None,
      right: None
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
    let mut root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(1))));
    println!("{:?}", root.unwrap().borrow().val); // cannot infer type for type parameter `Borrowed`
    root.unwrap().get_mut().val = 2; // cannot borrow data in an `Rc` as mutable
}
```

Comment: You have two independent problems. The first one is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25297447/1233251): `root` is moved after calling `unwrap()`. The second one is because you are expected to use `borrow_mut()` instead of `get_mut()`. The latter uses typical inherent mutability instead of interior mutability.

Comment: Why do you wrap the root in RefCell, Rc and Option? Just `let mut root = TreeNode::new(1)`, then populate branches

Comment: `Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>` implies the nodes can be shared by multiple parents. Is that the case? I'd expect nodes in a tree to own their children, in a `Box<TreeNode>` say.

Comment: Why it is Rc<RefCell<...>> is out of the scope of the question. The implementation has been given, and I can't change a single byte of it.

Comment: @AlexLarionov because it is in the function signature. I get Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, not TreeNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(1))));
let mut v = RefCell::borrow(root.as_ref().unwrap()).val) // Too verbose, but I do not know a brief way.
println!("{}", v); // 1
root.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().val += 1;
v = RefCell::borrow(root.as_ref().unwrap()).val)
println!("{}", v); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can safely `unwrap` the value if you know it's `Some(T)`. The `Rc<T>` should work like a transparent container that derefs on method calls, so you can generally treat an `Rc<T>` as a `T`, or specifically a `RefCell<T>` in your case, then you can interact with the value inside the `RefCell` using the `borrow` and `borrow_mut` methods. Example:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

// Definition for a binary tree node.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
  pub val: i32,
  pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
  pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

impl TreeNode {
  #[inline]
  pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    TreeNode {
      val,
      left: None,
      right: None
    }
  }
}


fn main() {
    let mut root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(1))));
    let mut root = root.unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", root.borrow().val); // read access
    root.borrow_mut().val = 2; // write access
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d75f9046e7db3d63796116172c90983b)

See also [Unwrap and access T from an Option<Rc<RefCell<T>>>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54012660/2766908)